# The multi-part identifier could not be bound error4

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I execute this code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE eligibility.FightersDB_2
AS
BEGIN 
    WHILE p.PersonID IS NOT NULL
    SELECT p.PersonFname, p.PersonLname, s.SchoolName,
    CASE
        WHEN  s.SchoolName IS NOT NULL THEN 'Eligible'
        ELSE 'Not Eligible'
    END AS Eligibility
    FROM [dbo].[School] s
    JOIN [dbo].[Department] d ON s.SchoolID = d.SchoolID
    JOIN [dbo].[Course] c ON d.DepartID = c.DepartID
    JOIN [dbo].[CLASS] cl ON c.CourseID = cl.CourseID
    JOIN [dbo].[PERSON_CLASS] pc ON cl.ClassID = pc.ClassID
    JOIN [dbo].[PERSON] p ON pc.PersonID = p.PersonID
    JOIN [dbo].[PERSON_EVENT] pe ON p.PersonID = pe.PersonID
    JOIN [dbo].[ROLE] r ON pe.RoleID = r.RoleID
    WHERE p.DateOfBirth <=  '1994-11-28'
END
```

I get this error:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure FightersDB_2, Line 4
>   The multi-part identifier "p.PersonID" could not be bound.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: are you joining [dbo].[School] ?

Comment: ^oops. I feel stupid. I will see if that works

Comment: so it eliminated 3 errors but i still have the first error

Comment: yea, what is wrong with it?

Comment: you can try `WHILE [dbo].[PERSON].PersonID IS NOT NULL`instead of `WHILE p.PersonID IS NOT NULL`

Comment: It still gives same error

Comment: Instead of using while y cant you use where p.PersonID IS NOT NULL at last

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure starts with a `WHILE` statement referring to `p.PersonID`. Alas at that point the alias `p` is not known as it is only visible within the query that is below it.

Also it is hard to say what you are trying to accomplish. Maybe you should explain that first and the community may give you some pointers on how to proceed.